# Do I need to differentiate between Chromecast device revisions?

Tags: chromecast

Given that Chromecast devices (both the 1st and the recently launched 2nd gen family) do only properly run when they have a working internet connection is it safe to assume that 1st and 2nd gen devices share the same public API?

Or do I need to do some magic number checking in my custom receiver code to check on which device revision the code is executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic is needed, they support identical set of APIs so developers don't need to differentiate them.